# How do i indent the output so that the countries are indented 2 spaces?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query that returns to me the output of region id in the left column,  region_name in the right column as well as the countries that fall under that region but i want to make the countries indented a couple of spaces...

```
SELECT region_id, region_name
FROM
(
    SELECT r.region_id, r.region_name, 0 AS ent
    FROM regions r

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.region_id, c.country_name, 1 AS ent
    FROM regions r
    INNER JOIN countries c
        ON r.region_id = c.region_id
)
ORDER BY region_id, ent, region_name;
```

```
1   Europe
1   Belgium
1   Denmark
1   France
1   Germany
1   Italy
1   Netherlands
1   Switzerland
1   United Kingdom
2   Americas
2   Argentina
2   Brazil
2   Canada
2   Mexico
2   United States of America
```

Comment: Why? If it's purely for display why not do it from your app code?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @shree.pat18 what do you mean app code?
do you know how to do it, regardless of whether it should be done or not?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oracle sql dev 11g
Also do you know if there is another method to writing this query without using a subquery in the from clause?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not saying ther is i just asking asking if there is another way of getting the same output?

Comment: Because you want to order by a column which you also don't want in the final output, I think you will need the subquery.

Comment: Would you like to be able to display the region names in boldface, too?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT r.region_id, CONCAT('  ', c.country_name), 1 AS ent
```

You might need to add an `AS` clause for the combined field to put it all together.

Comment: `+` is proprietary SQL Server syntax, in Oracle (and all other DBMSes) it's `'  ' || c.country_name`

Comment: Thanks, that might help. But no mention of Oracle was made.

Comment: But SQL Server wasn't mentioned, too :-)

Comment: @PeterB Sorry mate but thanks for the help !
Could you tell me if there is way of writing the same query without using another query in the from clause?

Comment: Changed answer to use CONCAT, which should be independent. And no, I don't know if or how the query could be simplified.